# Sum $y(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\cos(kx)|}{k}$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I have been trying to solve $$y(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\cos(kx)|}{k}$$ however, this is proving to be more difficult than I had hoped, and cannot seem to figure this out.

What I have figured out so far are the simpler sums:
$$y_1(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^k}{k} = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\text{sgn}(x')}{1-|x'|}dx' = -\ln(1-|x|)$$
$$y_2(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k x)}{k} = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2(1-\cos (x))) $$

I have tried using the same method for the absolute value of cosine that I did for the regular cosine sum, which is just -

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k} = \Re \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k}\right) $$ but since $$|\Re(z)| \neq \Re(||z||)$$ for a complex z, I'm not too sure how to finish this and would appreciate a hint.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not try $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$?

Comment: Well for $x=\pi$ the series is equal to harmonic series which diverges.So what are you exactly asking for?

Comment: I should have stated this earlier, however cases like that aren't too important to me, since I'm only really concerned with the values of x that will give me a convergent sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sum diverges for any real number $x$. Here's a sketch of the proof:

Assume first that $\frac x{2\pi}$ is irrational. In this case, the multiples of $x$ are uniformly distributed (mod $2\pi$). In particular, asymptotically $25\%$ of the multiples of $x$ are between $-\frac\pi4$ and $\frac\pi4$ (mod $2\pi$). For all these multiples, the corresponding term in the sum defining $y(x)$ is at least $\frac1{k\sqrt2}$. And if $K$ is any set of integers with positive density, then $\sum_{k\in S} \frac1k$ diverges (since the other terms are all nonnegative).

On the other hand, $\frac x{2\pi}$ is rational, say with denominator $d$, then every $d$th term in the sum equals $\frac1k$, and so the sum diverges for the same reason as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never really thought to actually check to see if it converged or not because I was just messing around on a graphing calculator and this is what came up (Guess its a little more misleading than I had anticipated since You have to approximate the sum): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o4vawgdmc4

Comment: It would be interesting to see what
$$\lim_{M\to\infty} \bigg( \frac1{\ln M} \sum_{k=1}^M \frac{|\cos kx|}k \bigg)$$
converges to. Probably $\frac2\pi$ (the average value of $|\cos y|$) if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your intention, this is trivially false @GregMartin. Consider $x = \pi$, in which case the sum is the harmonic series $\sim \log M + \mathcal O(1)$ and the limit is clearly $1$. Alternatively, we could choose $x = \pi/2$ in which case we get $$\lim_{M\to\infty} \bigg( \frac1{2\log M} \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor M/2 \rfloor} \frac{1}{k} \bigg) = \lim_{M\to\infty} \frac{H_{\lfloor M/2 \rfloor}}{2 \log M} = \lim_{M\to\infty} \frac{\log(\lfloor M/2 \rfloor) + \mathcal O(1)}{2 \log M} = \tfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake—I meant to assume that $x/\pi$ is irrational, not $x$ itself.